# Horizontal scroll bar in combo box in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am working with GXT to develop a web application. But I am finding difficulty in adding the horizontal scroll bar in combo box. Some of the items of the combo box have large text and I can't see all the text when I see the combo box items. I am not finding a way to set a horizontal scroll bar to the combo box.
When I searched in the net I found that we have to implement template for that, but nothing I have found useful. Can you help me in this regard?

Comment: Is there any other way to implement the horizontal scroll bar in the combo box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be super useful for you, but we found it tough to create a nice xtemplate for h-scroll.
Instead we added tooltips for any items that are longer than the combo.
I must say that it works nicely.

Comment: Hi Davids, do you have any idea how to set tool tips in combo box?

Comment: On the combo :

setSimpleTemplate("<span title=\"{"+getDisplayField()+"}\">{"+getDisplayField()+"}</span>");

Comment: Thanx Davids. I will try to implement that.

Answer (score 3):

You can change combobox style from gxt-all.css at location "war\resources\css\gxt-all.css"

Add  "overflow: visible !important;" to x-combo-list-inner

`.x-combo-list-inner {
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow: visible !important;
}`

Comment: Thanx a lot Yusuf for your reply. I was looking for implementing the horizontal bar from quite a long time.

Comment: Your welcome :)  You can change other attributes from other style classes about this situation. You can put horizontal scrollbar or increase the visible area as per text length.

Comment: I don't know if this is due to a GXT update or what, but I also needed to add this line to my CSS to get the scrollbars to appear: `.x-combo-list-item { overflow:visible !important; }`

Comment: This is not a GXT update, this is just a workaround to show long text in combobox.